# How to retrieve values from json object using awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed, json

I have the following json

```
[root@mdfdevha1 ~]#  echo "$Group_ID"
[ {
  "id" : "e27206c0-aeb6-43db-acda-c4ba43233071",
  "name" : "A1",
  "path" : "/A1",
  "subGroups" : [ ]
}, {
  "id" : "89f3bd6a-33a9-4e02-9fe3-eae660c5a6cf",
  "name" : "Admin_UserGroup",
  "path" : "/Admin_UserGroup",
  "subGroups" : [ ]
}, {
  "id" : "cdc2bce5-c3bb-4b88-bdaf-d87b8bb6c644",
  "name" : "Group104",
  "path" : "/Group104",
  "subGroups" : [ ]
}, {
  "id" : "a0d749f2-ab6c-4c27-ad55-3357eaab9527",
  "name" : "Group105",
  "path" : "/Group105",
  "subGroups" : [ ]
}, {
  "id" : "fbf99c34-d50d-408b-8d19-9713f9af3e3a",
  "name" : "Group106",
  "path" : "/Group106",
  "subGroups" : [ ]
}, {
  "id" : "ebd8336f-4017-4fb1-8035-153ae1d9ba37",
  "name" : "Group201",
  "path" : "/Group201",
  "subGroups" : [ ]
}, {
  "id" : "38f4aef7-caf0-4430-9e61-1ae7026e872f",
  "name" : "Group202",
  "path" : "/Group202",
  "subGroups" : [ ]
}, {
  "id" : "436a0f4a-8b1b-4d7d-a014-fcec3513644e",
  "name" : "Group203",
  "path" : "/Group203",
  "subGroups" : [ ]
}, {
  "id" : "41962c5f-e7e9-4748-b81f-e3f1880b78de",
  "name" : "Sure_Groups",
  "path" : "/Sure_Groups",
  "subGroups" : [ {
    "id" : "593dfe69-1ed8-4649-bde4-a277166333f8",
    "name" : "Test1",
    "path" : "/Sure_Groups/Test1",
    "subGroups" : [ ]
  } ]
}, {
  "id" : "6856b69b-9113-46e1-90c6-f34548625278",
  "name" : "UG_1",
  "path" : "/UG_1",
  "subGroups" : [ ]
}, {
  "id" : "6496a0fe-b41f-4f0f-9eb9-5ef749c9130a",
  "name" : "UG_12",
  "path" : "/UG_12",
  "subGroups" : [ ]
}, {
  "id" : "71a5f5ae-bf91-4cdf-ab3c-c09ca15080d6",
  "name" : "UG_1456",
  "path" : "/UG_1456",
  "subGroups" : [ ]
}, {
  "id" : "385ea518-1d40-45f7-afcd-c0488ff02e97",
  "name" : "UG_26",
  "path" : "/UG_26",
  "subGroups" : [ {
    "id" : "a4064e3a-e2e3-47bb-99b8-9f7fadb0bc20",
    "name" : "Test1",
    "path" : "/UG_26/Test1",
    "subGroups" : [ ]
  } ]
}, {
  "id" : "9c5efedc-b901-4dcf-bbc8-8ddeaa5d84f7",
  "name" : "UG_266",
  "path" : "/UG_266",
  "subGroups" : [ ]
}, {
  "id" : "c5eb3064-752c-4f7c-b4f1-ac59f50397dd",
  "name" : "Usergroup_01",
  "path" : "/Usergroup_01",
  "subGroups" : [ ]
}, {
  "id" : "d39dc10c-558b-433e-82b4-e01a8f1d8998",
  "name" : "Usergroup_02",
  "path" : "/Usergroup_02",
  "subGroups" : [ ]
} ]
```

How to get particular data with `awk`  or `sed` .I need to get data where `name="Admin_UserGroup"`?

#### EDIT #1

Thanks to **Hossein Vatani** for his answer and here are the final commands:

```
$ /opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh get groups -r T0_Realm > Group.json
$ GROUP_ID_TEMP=$(grep -B1 -A0 '"name" : "Admin_UserGroup"' Group.json)
$ GROUP_ID=$(echo $GROUP_ID_TEMP | cut -d : -f2 | awk -F\" '{print $2}')
```

Comment: I'd expect a python interpreter to be present on most systems today. If it does, your problem has a trivial solution.

Comment: from python i already done it but in server python wont be available .

Comment: This is marked as a duplicate, but it's not a duplicate, since the question is about awk and sed.

Comment: Here is another way:
    cat json|xargs|cut -c 4-|awk 'BEGIN{RS="}, {";ORS="\n";FS=", ";FS=", "; OFS=";"} { gsub (" : ", "=",$0);print $1,$2,$3}'|while read line
    do
   eval $line
   [ $name == "Admin_UserGroup" ] && echo $id $path
    done

Step by step:
`xargs` - put everything in one line
`cut -c 4-` - cuts first 3 chars which are `{ [`
`awk.'{BEGIN ...`
`RS="}, {";` - Tell to awk `}, {` threat as record separator.
`ORS="\n";` - Tell to awk we want `\n` to be new record separator.

Comment: `FS=", ";` - Tell to awk we have field separator as `, `.
`OFS=";"` - Tell to awk we want to have field separator as `;`.
`gsub (" : ", "=",$0)` - replace ` : ` into `=`
`print $1,$2,$3` - print only 3 first fields 
`while read line ...` - read line by line our records
`eval $line` - execute them (assign values to variables)
 `$name == "Admin_UserGroup" ] && echo $id $path` - check if variable `$name` has appropriate value and `&&` print what we want

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to your consideration for basic commands, if your file has structure exactly as shown, `grep` may help you:

```
$ grep -B2 -A3 '"name" : "Admin_UserGroup"' File
```

but if all in one line:

```
$ sed -E 's/\},\s*\{/\},\n\{/g' File | grep  '"name" : "Admin_UserGroup"'
```

Using your original example, you'd use my solution like so:

```
$ echo "$Group_ID" | grep ...
```

Comment: Can same thing use for sed as well rather than using File?

Comment: Structure of JSON will same but position of the record may change .

Comment: `sed` could it but it goes complicated and I think sed has a different duty, and your issue related to `grep` duty.

Answer (score 16):

Using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$Group_ID" | jq '.[] | select(.name == "Admin_UserGroup")'
{
  "id": "89f3bd6a-33a9-4e02-9fe3-eae660c5a6cf",
  "name": "Admin_UserGroup",
  "path": "/Admin_UserGroup",
  "subGroups": []
}
```

This selects all objects in the array whose `name` key corresponds to a value of `Admin_UserGroup`.

Comment: For me jq cant be use as client wont allow to install any third party api in the production environment

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Well, the client will get code that is unstable instead then.

Comment: means if same can be achieve through `sed `or `awk `it would be unstable ?

Comment: JSON is structured data, by using tools that are unaware of the structure (awk, sed) you run the risk of creating regex matching that's very brittle and will fail because it's not taking any care to respect that the JSON data is structured.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi JSON is a structured document format in the same genre as XML. Parsing such documents with anything other than a dedicated parser is error prone. JSON has rules for how data is encoded and quoted, where keys goes and where newlines are allowed, etc.

Comment: @slm While I agree with your comment applied to sed, I don't agree with respect to awk, which is far from restricted to regex.

Comment: @Pac0 - fair point.

Comment: @Pac0 I agree that `awk` is not restricted to regular expressions. I do not agree that `awk` is well suited to do JSON parsing in.

Answer (score 7):

You can use JSON.awk:

```
awk -f JSON.awk -v file1.json file2.json
```

https://github.com/step-/JSON.awk

Comment: To be a complete (self-contained) Answer, the code should be here in the Answer box, not a link.

Comment: do one need to copy in answers the whole source of every tool that can perform jobs ?

Comment: @Pac0 - yes, you need to put JSON.awk on every system where you'll want to use this.

Comment: @Pac0 or, if you meant that as a reply to my comment, answers should contain the necessary information for someone to take it to their system and use it. Systems (should) have `awk` installed, or else it's turtles all the way down to hand-writing your own compiler. See our Help Center regarding [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) and [Why are answers no longer being accepted from my account?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans) both of which discourage link-only answers.

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes, that was concerning your comment. Thank you for the answer and the links. I just made a (pending) edit to incoporate the source in the answer. I was afraid it was a bit too long, but I forgot that code blocks do use scroll bars.

Comment: @Pac0 - i rejected the edit b/c that AWK.json file is a 259 line script.

Comment: The [OP rejected `jq`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459805/how-to-retrieve-values-from-json-object-using-awk-or-sed#comment836086_459807) because it is a "third party api".  I think that JSON.awk is just as much of a "third party api", albeit in script form instead of c.

Comment: While this solution may work it has only one committer and 16 commits. If you look for a stable long term solution, this may not be the best option.

Comment: patrik, but it is in source control, and has automated tests. I don't see any automated tests for the other suggested approaches to parsing json with awk.

Answer (score 2):

With recent versions of `ksh93`, you can parse json data into a ksh93 compound variable with `read -m json`:

```
print -r -- "$Group_ID" | IFS= read -rm json v
for ((i = 0; i < ${#v[@]}; i++)); do
  if [[ ${v[i].name} = Admin_UserGroup ]]; then
    print -r -- "${v[i]}"
  fi
done
```

It outputs:

```
(
        id=89f3bd6a-33a9-4e02-9fe3-eae660c5a6cf
        name=Admin_UserGroup
        path=/Admin_UserGroup
        typeset -C subGroups
)
```

Instead of `print -r -- "${v[i]}"`, you can print `${v[i].path}` or any other information from that compound variable.

Comment: I am getting this error -> `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: @SubodhJoshi, yes, as I said, it's for the `ksh93` shell (recent versions: ksh93v- and newer), not the `bash` shell. Most of `bash`'s syntax and features have been copied from ksh, however it's far from being a full clone. In particular `bash` doesn't support ksh's compound variables.

Comment: Do i have to install a new library ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{if($0~/"AdminUserGroup"/) {NR=NR-1;print $0; NR=NR+2;print $0; } }'file1
```

In this way we can print info of lines near the searched string. Also I think instead of printing it we can put all those inside an an array also:

```
$ awk '{if($0~/"AdminUserGroup"/) {NR=NR-1;arr[$i]=(print $0);i=$((i+1)); \
    NR=NR+2; arr[$i]=(print $0); } }'file1.
```

Then we can use array details.

Comment: How to pass a variable in place of file ?